# How can I Start-Process powershell.exe with some string splitter?

Tags: powershell, intellisense, powershell-4.0

I want to start `powershell.exe` with a scriptblock like this (it's working fine):

```
Start-Process powershell.exe {
  Get-Help 
  Get-Process
}
```

But this script doesn't work:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe {
  $string = "123xAbcxEFG"
  $split1,$split2,$split3 = $string.Split("x")
  Write-Output $split1
  Write-Output $split2
  Write-Output $split3
  sleep 10
}
```

I think I need `Add-Type -AssemblyName "SomeNameSpace"`, but how can I find that namespace? Any intellisense or something like this?

Comment: Can you see what the error message says? It just flashes and then closes the window for me

Comment: i can't see error . powershell window disappear immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use start-job it's actually start new powershell process . and you can do is easy. like this :

```
start-job
```

for more help use :

```
get-help start-job
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the quotes. It works, if you e.g. put additional single quotes around your double quotes. It also works with triple double quotes.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe  {
$string = """123xAbcxEFG"""
$split1,$split2,$split3 = $string.split("""x""")
Write-Output $split1
Write-Output $split2
Write-Output $split3
sleep 10
}
```

How I changed your code to catch the error (without the additional double quotes):

```
$ScriptBlock = {
  $string = "123xAbcxEFG"
  $split1,$split2,$split3 = $string.split("x")
  Write-Output $split1
  Write-Output $split2
  Write-Output $split3
  sleep 10
}

Start-Process powershell -argumentlist "-noexit -command $ScriptBlock"
```

Comment: I changed my answer, because there are several ways. I also updated how I found the problem.

Comment: At line:3 char:42
+  $split1,$split2,$split3 = $string.split(x)
+~
Missing ')' in method call.
At line:3 char:42
+  $split1,$split2,$split3 = $string.split(x)
+                                          ~
Unexpected token 'x' in expression or statement.
At line:3 char:43
+  $split1,$split2,$split3 = $string.split(x)
+                                           ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall

Comment: see my changed answer with the triple double quotes.

Comment: yes, because this error gives you a hint that the quotes are not working as you did expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use start-job it's actually start new powershell process . and you can do is easy.
like this :

```
$script= {get-help "dir"}
start-job -scriptblock $script
```