# Run PowerShell script via command prompt

Tags: powershell, parameters

I need to run PowerShell script that is working fine when using PowerShell ISE/Shell however I need to run this same command using dos commandline and then It's not working as expected.

PowerShell script/command
`Get-FalconUninstallToken -Id <AgentID> -PipelineVariable "<ClientID>,<ClientSecret>" | select uninstall_token | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders -OutVariable MaintToken`
Output: 12345567788

If I try the same using commandline I keep getting prompted for ClientID, ClientSecret
`powershell.exe -command Get-FalconUninstallToken -Id <clientid> -PipelineVariable "<clientID>,<clientSecret>"`
I've tried various other combination but so far not really succeeding any suggestions would be appreciated

I've also tried with PowerShell script instead of -command -File   but same result.  For some reason when trying this using Dos command prompt the ClientID,ClientSecret paramters are not accepted or I'm doing something not right.

Thx for all the help

Comment: The operations after `-Command` need to be a block of code, not just a list of commands and vairables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342632/how-to-use-powershell-exe-with-command-using-a-scriptblock-and-parameters

Comment: Try single quotes vs double quotes.  A pipeline variable is like "a", no comma (or dollar sign).

Comment: I've tried with single quotes but no luck.   I'm confused why it works fine from PowerShell (Shell) and not from command prompt, for some reason it does not like the -PipelineVariable.

Comment: I don't think you understand what -pipelinevariable does.

Comment: @js2010 you probably right regarding -pipelinevariable but way I see it is that when I run the script inside PowerShell it works just fine and when I'm running from commandline then it does not work correctly.  So makes me think that behavior is slightly different and that's what I currently try to understand
Even if modify script to the below (these are dummy values)

#$args1 ="1,2"
#$ClientID = "3"
#Get-FalconUninstallToken -Id $ClientID -PipelineVariable $args
When i run the script from PowerShell command it works just fine. WIll look furhter for a solution

Comment: The linked duplicate (accepted answer) provides detailed guidance, but the short of it is: Enclose the entire PowerShell command passed to `-Command` in `"..."`, and either use `'...'` quoting inside the PowerShell command or escape embedded `"` chars. as `\"`

Comment: @Scepticalist, script blocks can only be used from inside PowerShell. (From outside PowerShell, you sometimes see the anti-pattern `powershell -c "& { ... }"`, but just `powershell -c "... "` is sufficient.)

Comment: The pipes need to be quoted so cmd doesn't run them.  You might as well drop -pipelinevariable since you don't really use it.